# Magento: Multiple rows for a single custom attribute of a catalog product?

Tags: magento, custom-attributes

Here's what I'm trying to do...

A given item in our store might be in multiple numerical "Product Groups". We also need to use those product groups to qualify/disqualify those items for coupons and sales rules.

If I define "Product Group" as custom attribute through EAV, the best I can do is set the Backend Model to "array", and have the multiple product groups saved as comma-delimited text in a varchar field. This is obviously less than ideal (and doesn't even convert back to an array on load).

Is there any way to have true one-to-many database rows for a product's custom attributes?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're referring to Categories.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just create a secondary category structure and just set the categories to be not shown in the navigation? Another option would be to use a new attribute set for each product group. It sounds like you're over complicating it with an attribute arrays, Both of these solutions will allow you to use coupons and sales rules.